# Want To Ditch Filemaker

Tags: database-design

I have been developing Filemaker pro for the last four years or so for a small machine shop erp/mrp system. Through Filemaker I have learned a bit about relational data base design and data modeling but I would really like to move onto something else that is open source and extremely flexible. I'm really open to learning anything have been self teaching myself C, Python, MySQL and a bunch of applescript. My question is really what do I need to know to make complex dynamic database using C, C++, Java, Python, html, xml, lisp, Unix, or whatever else that is fast, reliable and extremely flexible on the front and back ends?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a question better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com, but I'll go there anyway.

Don't try to roll your own database system at this point.  You can learn relational databases on MySQL, PostgreSQL, or SQLite, for starters.  All those are freely available.  You can at a minimum learn SQL to use with any of those tools.  Most programming languages in wide use have some library that can interface with these database systems.

Learn more about data modeling, particularly about normalization and indexing, while you're at it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was a bit of crazy blurb. I definitely do not want to roll my own back end now. But I know the standards of data modeling, normalization and indexing I've done all that in very complex manner within Filemaker. But its time I build some sort of SQL back-end to play with. I guess what I wanted to know is were to start to increase my front end flexibility which can be very constraining in filemaker. I'd really like to work in python and pyTables looks interesting too.

Comment: I meant PyTables as a back end tool of course. wow, this thread is in the wrong place and out of control.